# Datatables and jquery not executing selector button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I cannot get my edit button to execute on a click.

Here's my HTML:

```
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
 <thead><tr><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Email Address</th><th>Actions</th></tr></thead> 
<tbody>
    <tr role="row" class="even">
       <td class="sorting_1">Someone</td>
       <td>Foryou</td>
       <td>someadd@gmail.com</td>
       <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info smallPadding edit">Edit</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type="button" class="btn btn-success smallPadding">Export</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger smallPadding">Delete</button>
       </td>
    </tr>
        <tr role="row" class="even">
       <td class="sorting_1">Someone</td>
       <td>Foryou</td>
       <td>someadd@gmail.com</td>
       <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info smallPadding edit">Edit</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type="button" class="btn btn-success smallPadding">Export</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger smallPadding">Delete</button>
       </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
 <tfoot><tr><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Email Address</th><th>Actions</th></tr></tfoot> 
</table>
```

And here is my Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jq(document).ready(function() {                
        jq('#example').DataTable( {
            "ajax": basePath + '/'+localeCodeShort +'/users/api/get-users',
             "columnDefs": [ {
                "targets": -1,
                "data": null,
                "defaultContent": "<button type='button' class='btn btn-info smallPadding edit'>Edit</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type='button' class='btn btn-success smallPadding'>Export</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type='button' class='btn btn-danger smallPadding'>Delete</button>"
            }]});   
        jq("#example tbody button.edit").on("click",function(){alert("hi");});                 
    });
</script>
```

Comment: can you add the full code or jsfiddle ?

Comment: added missing code @Sven.hig

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, this seems to be working.

```js
jq = $;

jq(function() {
  jq('#example').DataTable({
    //            "ajax": basePath + '/'+localeCodeShort +'/users/api/get-users',
    "columnDefs": [{
      "targets": -1,
      "data": null,
      "defaultContent": "<button type='button' class='btn btn-info smallPadding edit'>Edit</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type='button' class='btn btn-success smallPadding'>Export</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type='button' class='btn btn-danger smallPadding'>Delete</button>"
    }]
  });
  jq("#example tbody button.edit").on("click", function() {
    alert("hi");
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js">
</script>
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Email Address</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr role="row" class="even">
      <td class="sorting_1">Someone</td>
      <td>Foryou</td>
      <td>someadd@gmail.com</td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info smallPadding edit">Edit</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type="button" class="btn btn-success smallPadding">Export</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger smallPadding">Delete</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="even">
      <td class="sorting_1">Someone</td>
      <td>Foryou</td>
      <td>someadd@gmail.com</td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info smallPadding edit">Edit</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type="button" class="btn btn-success smallPadding">Export</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger smallPadding">Delete</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Email Address</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with jQuery Datatables, but I suspect you are attaching the click event listener to the hardcoded buttons, but when the ajax data loads, the new buttons do not have the event lister attached. You may want to check out more about the buttons API for datatables [https://datatables.net/reference/option/buttons](https://datatables.net/reference/option/buttons), as it appears dataTables has quite an extensive means of handling buttons in tables.